# What makes a pthread the "main" thread?

Tags: pthreads, glfw

What makes a pthread the "main thread"?

I'm asking because some GLFW functions [must only be called from the main thread](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.4/intro_guide.html#:%7E:text=made%20non%2Dreentrant.-,Thread%20safety,whole%20library%20is%20thread%2Dunsafe.). I understand the concept of thread safety. But what is special about the main thread? Why can't I run all GLFW functions from a non-main thread?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43290721/50617 probably answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What makes a pthread the "main thread"?

In a POSIX environment (where you would find pthreads), the term usually means the *initial* thread of the program, in which the (first) entry into `main()` occurs.  That is [how the GLFW documentation uses it](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro_guide.html#thread_safety).

> But what is special about the main thread?

Pthreads itself does not specially distinguish a program's initial thread.  The initial call to `main()` within is distinguished by the fact that returning from that call terminates the whole program, but that's not what GLFW is interested in.  The docs explain:

> Initialization, termination, event processing and the creation and destruction of windows, cursors and OpenGL and OpenGL ES contexts are all restricted to the main thread *due to limitations of one or several platforms*.

(Emphasis added)

It seems that [GLFW's "one or several platforms" mostly means MacOS](https://sourceforge.net/p/glfw/discussion/247562/thread/ce767110/#97c9), though Windows and X11 each have their own idiosyncrasies that play in this area.  GLFW says "Screw all that. It works everywhere to restrict most operations to the main thread, so that's what we're going to require." That makes it easier for them and for you the application programmer.

> Why can't I run all GLFW functions from a non-main thread?

Because GLFW aims to be cross-platform, and that doesn't work on MacOS.  If you mean why can't you call GLFW functions from arbitrary threads then that also doesn't, in general, work on Windows. If you mean you want to designate a specific thread on which all GLFW operations will be performed then that could in principle be done on both Windows and Unix, but then why not choose the main thread? Putting your GUI event loop in the main thread is pretty standard.

Comment: Thank you. That helps. Can you speculate as to why MacOS (Cocoa I guess?) restricts API calls to the main thread? I understand that I can just do the standard thing of calling everything from the main thread, but I'd love to know why someone decided to put that limitation in the API. How can MacOS/Cocoa even determine if a thread calling an API function is the main thread?

Comment: @hanno, as far as I understand it, the limitation on the Mac side is a fundamental one of cocoa.  I hesitate to speculate on specific technical aspects of that design, but I don't find it altogether unreasonable.  Nor does it seem uncharacteristic of Apple to designate a specific Right Way to do things on its platform.